# I can't optimize with parallelization of a program

Tags: c++, openmp, parallel-processing

I'm trying to point out the difference between serial and parallel program with OpenMP. I work on scientific Linux.
This is a simple program that performs a sum and a multiplication, then sum the results.

I used the function `omp_get_wtime()` to check the execution time and the result is that the part parallelized runs more slowly than the serial part.
I think the problem is in the cases, because both threads enter in the switch, and this increases the execution time.
I wish that the first thread makes the sum and the second makes the multiplication, in order to speed the final result. Can you help me?

At the beginning of the program i use:

```
#define NUM_THREADS 2
...
omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
```

This is the program:

```
double a,b,c,d,g,timer,timer2;

printf("Insert 2 numbers \n"); cin >> a; cin >> b;

timer = omp_get_wtime();

c = a+b;
d = a*b;
g = c+d;


printf("the result is: %f\n\n",g);
printf("time: %f seconds\n\n",omp_get_wtime()-timer);




timer2 = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel
{
    switch ( omp_get_thread_num() )
    {
        case 1: c=a+b; 
        case 2: d=a*b;
    }              
}
g = c+d; 

printf("parallel time:  %f seconds\n\n",g,omp_get_wtime()-timer2);
```

Comment: Note: Most of the elapsed time you're measuring here is spent in the first printf statement

Comment: Also note: even the switch statement is likely to be more expensive then your calculations (unless it is optimized out at least), not to mention the measuring (and distribution of work onto threads). So really you measure just about anything but the time needed for the calculations (btw your last `printf` is broken). Trying to time calculations which don't take thousands of clock cycles is generally pretty much pointless (and for openmp to be beneficial you'll likely need at least tens of thousands of operations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some constant overhead to spinning up the threads and distributing the work. For a single trivial operation like a multiplication, this overhead far outweighs the time saved by performing the operations in parallel.

You're more likely to see benefits if you give the threads some actual work to do.

Comment: Thanks! Now i try to do something...
If you, or someone else, have any idea i'll welcome it.